# How to sublass ndarray to transform as rvalue, but preserve lvalue

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to subclass `np.ndarray` such that my new custom array has the following properties,

1. When defining the array, I would also provide a `transform_fwd` function, as a class parameter.
2. Whenever this array is used in any computation, it applies and provides the transformed value.
3. But when assigning the values to the array, I should be able to use original "un-transformed" values

i.e. API should be like:

```py
my_arr = MyNpArr([10.,100.,1000.], transform_fwd=lambda x: np.log(x))

y = 2 * my_arr # equivalent to y = 2 * np.log(my_arr)
print(y) # 2 4 6

my_arr[2] = 10000
y = 2 * my_arr
print(y) # 2 4 8
```

Is it possible

Comment: Does it have to be a subclass of `ndarray`?  Often it's easier to make a whole new class, with an array(s) as attribute.  You could also focus on writing one or more functions that manipulate arrays in the desired way, and may be later package them as a class and methods.

Comment: I am open to have a whole new class as well. But would like to keep the same API. I was not sure how to make sure that when I call write the class instance, it behaves as stored numpy array.

Comment: "rvalue" "lvalue" are not really applicable to Python.

Comment: In any case, I too suggest simply not subclassing `ndarray`, and create your own class.

Comment: what is the value of `my_arr`, without any operation on it?

Comment: As in? Basically I would like to have a numpy like container, that can seemlessly work with my numpy code. When used in an expression it should provide a transformed numpy array. But when I need to assign values to that array I should be able to do it in original space. So if i do `my_arr[0] = 100`, `my_arr * 2 ` should be `2 * 2 = 4`

Comment: Normally when we do computations on/with an array, we get a new array.  We have to takes special steps to modify the array's own values.  It's not clear if you are trying something else.  I can imagine defining a class that has two arrays, one with the "original" values, and another with some sort of transformed values.